# Android: Prevent installation on tablets

Tags: android, installation, tablet

My company developed a product that was designed for handsets, but unfortunately tablet owners can still download and install it and it looks like a terrible mess.  Obviously, this has led to complaints, so I started looking for where I went wrong.  I checked the manifest, and here is what is in the supports-screen section:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/><uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

Shouldn't xlarge screens be false by default?  On the application page in my play account it says xlarge screens are supported when they really aren't.  So I tried including `android:xlargeScreens` but of course this fails since that was introduced in API level 9.  What can I do to prevent tablet installs?  Or do I just have to write "TABLETS NOT SUPPORTED" in the description...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for using `xlargeScreens`, just compile your app with API level 9, you don't need to actually use it. Earlier versions will ignore attributes they don't understand.

You could also:

- fix the app :)
- unselect particular tablet devices in the Market/Play console. Not ideal, but removing the top 3-4 tablets will cover most users.

Comment: Setting the maxSdkVersion="10" wouldn't work out so well unless you're happy to ignore ICS phones.

Comment: Hm, looks like `maxSdkVersion` has been deprecated.

Comment: Right, of course. Not too many of those, but still. In any case, it looks like it's been deprecated.

Comment: You mean set the `targetSdkVersion` to 9?  I tried that and it still complained about the lack of an xlargeScreen identifier...

Comment: Open project properties, select 'Android', set 'Project build target' to 'Android 2.3.1' (API level 9) or 'Android 2.3.3' (API level 10).

Comment: Rats, I am using Titanium so I don't know how to find that, but I feel like I should be able to set it if I search the Titanium docs.

Comment: Anyway, I'm sure this answer is correct.  I just have to figure out how to apply it to titanium...>< so I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent downloading on tablets, you have to use the `compatible-screens` attribute and set all extra-large and large screens to be off for MDPI/HDPI.  The `supports-screens` attribute only filters out smaller screens.

Comment: This is only available starting in API level 9